# Invertibility Error while calculating Moving average in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am getting the following error while running a SARIMA model.

> ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible 
>   You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order,  or
>   you can pass your own start_params.

My code is as follows:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
#AR Model
model = ARIMA(ts_log,order=(3,1,3))
results_AR = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(ts_log_shifted)
plt.plot(results_AR.fittedvalues,color='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_AR.fittedvalues-ts_log_shifted["PRB Utilization"])**2))
print('AR Model Plot')
```

Can someone help me with what error I might be making? I do not wish to use SARIMAX right now.